# Why sell stocks when inflation is high?

Tags: united-states, stocks, inflation, economics

It doesn’t make much sense to me why the stock market (sometimes, today isn’t really an example) does more poorly when inflation is high. If CPI was high, I would think you’d want your $$$ invested in something else so inflation isn’t eating it, right? People selling their stock is meaning people are trading their shares for USD again. If inflation was high, I’d want to invest in the market and (hopefully) beat inflation so I’m not theoretically losing.

Can someone tell me why there’s sometimes a sell-off in the stock market due to high CPI levels?

Comment: Instant sell-off, or gradual decline?

Comment: @RonJon I’m talking more instant or short-term decline like anywhere from a couple of days to a few weeks.

Comment: In that case, the answer to "why sell" is "panic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any transaction, there must be a buyer and a seller so even when newspapers talk about a "sell-off" or "selling pressure", there are always an equal number of buyers and sellers.  Whether the price of stocks are going up or down or staying the same, you've got the same number of buyers and sellers.

If inflation increases and nothing else changes, a stock is intrinsically worth less under basically any valuation model you'd care to choose.  If you're trying to determine what a share of Acme Widgets is worth, that's going to depend on the present value of the profits Acme is going to make in the future.  In order to determine the present value of a fixed amount of profit a year from now, you need to apply the discount rate.  And the discount rate will increase when inflation increases because a dollar a year from now is worth less when inflation is 5% than when it is 1%.

Picking the simplest stock valuation model, the [dividend discount model](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/valuation/dividend-discount-model/)

```
Fair Price of Stock = (Dividend Amount)/ (Cost of Capital - Growth Rate of Dividend)
```

where

```
Cost of Capital = Risk-Free Rate + Beta * Market Risk Premium
```

When inflation increases, the risk-free rate increases (investors want the government to pay more interest when they borrow money in a 10% inflation environment than in a 1% inflation environment).  If nothing else changes-- the dividend remains the same and the growth rate of dividends remain the same (beta and the market risk premium are functionally constants in this discussion)-- then the fair price of the stock declines when inflation increases.  If everyone in the market knows the fair price has declined, people will buy and sell at a lower price and the market price of the stock will decline.

Of course, this **vastly** simplifies the reality of the situation.  There are *lots* of different valuation models that make *lots* of different assumptions.  Different market participants use different models, input different parameters, etc.  Some market participants pay attention to valuation models, some don't.  When inflation rises, different companies are affected differently.  Some companies are stuck absorbing some or all of the increase in prices of their inputs because they're locked into contracts with their customers.  Some companies can pass along price increases from their suppliers so their dividends and dividend growth rate would simply increase along with inflation so inflation wouldn't change their prices.  Some companies can use an inflationary environment to increase prices and see their growth rate increase faster than inflation.

Comment: "The first casualty of rising inflation is stock market valuations. It's only once valuations become normal or depressed (a decline that would offset a nearly 2.5x increase in the CPI here) that the benefit to nominal cash flow growth dominates the negative impact on valuations." - John Hussman, mutual fund manager https://twitter.com/hussmanjp/status/1253359862106505219

Comment: So bottom line is that almost every valuation model is skewed for the worse when inflation rises? Your answer implies what time frames (long or short term or both)?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins - Every valuation model will say that the current fair value of a stock will decline if inflation increases and everything else remains the same.  As a practical matter, it is unlikely that everything else remains the same.  Depending on the model and the company and the assumptions you use, some stocks will do better in an inflationary environment and some will do worse.  But the first order effect is that increased inflation decreases today's fair price.

Comment: A historical example: Short-term, spiking discount rates causes stock market crashes (e.g. 1968-1974). Medium-term, the market stays at a low valuation as inflation hurts profits and capital formation (e.g. the late 1970s). Long-term, profit margins return as inflation moderates and corporate pricing power overcomes the permanently-higher price levels (e.g. the 1980s).

Answer (score 1):

Real returns (returns minus inflation) are lowest during high inflationary periods. This is due to a variety of reasons, but some of the most important are that:

- ubiquitous inflation pressures companies to increase the prices of goods and services, leading to less sales and ultimately worse earnings. consumer staple companies are more immune to this, because passing the inflation costs to consumers is easier than for cyclical or discretionary sectors
- inflation can lead to higher interest rates, which makes it harder for companies to acquire or recompense their debts, and the interest expense increases, corroding earnings further; this particularly implicates growth companies that are trying to finally have positive earnings
- dividend-paying stocks, like fixed-rate bonds, often deteriorate in high-inflation environments; the cash payments redistributed to shareholders is worth less than it was before inflation.

So what some investors do during inflationary periods is liquidate significant portions of their equities portfolio and redeploy those funds toward conventional inflation hedges, such as real estate and commodities. Inflation-indexed bonds and CDOs are also popular.

Answer (score 0):

> People selling their stock is meaning people are trading their shares for USD again.

Regardless of what inflation is doing, I need USD to buy groceries, pay my electric bill, etc. If I am retired and living off of my investment portfolio, I will need to sell assets to cover my expenses, regardless of CPI. I might try to do some predictive planning around *when* I convert assets to cash (e.g. yearly vs. monthly), but inevitably I do have to sell (or go back to work).

Sure, I'd like to keep my money invested invested to beat inflation so that I can pay my future living expenses, but I still need to pay my current expenses *now*.

Note that this selling isn't *due to high CPI*, it just happens regardless.

Comment: "this selling isn't *due to high CPI*, it just happens regardless" means that you didn't answer the question.  (There's an acronym for *retirees* needing to sell during a downturn, but I can't remember what it is.)

Comment: @RonJohn it answers the question posed on the title, and responds to the reasoning provided in the first paragraph, both of with focus on the motivation of an individual. The question posed in the second paragraph assumes a causal link that may not exist

Comment: Not everyone -- and especially *traders* -- needs to sell securities in order to pay the bills.

Comment: I don't follow. The reason doesn't apply to everyone therefore it is not a legitimate reason to sell?

Comment: "You" aren't selling **because inflation is high**; you're selling because you need to eat, and like electricity.  See his comment, "I’m talking more **instant or short-term decline** like anywhere from a couple of days to a few weeks."

Comment: So high CPI has nothing to do with price drops?<—explain that. And I think what RonJohn is saying is that *most* traders don’t need to sell to pay bills, especially if they’re receive monthly checks for dividends, pensions (or whatever)

Comment: I was answering from a personal finance perspective, rather than economic.

Comment: @RonJohn *"You" aren't selling __because inflation is high__* is exactly my point. People sell stocks when inflation is high because they sell stocks for *reasons other than inflation*.

Comment: Except for traders who think (or panic) that that the market is going to decline, and decide to "get out now while the getting's good".  IOW, sell high.